# Rational Roots (with Lots of Square Roots!)

Tags: polynomials, roots

Find the smallest positive integer $a,$ greater than 1000, such that the equation $$\sqrt{a - \sqrt{a + x}} = x$$ has a rational root.

Squaring both sides we have $a-\sqrt{a+x}=x^2.$ We shall not square again as that gives a quartic in $x.$ Rearranging, we have $$-x^2+a-\sqrt{a+x}=0 \implies x^2-a+\sqrt{a+x}=0.$$ How would we continue? Solutions? (I don't have one in my book.)

Comment: Why don't you want a quartic in $x$?

Comment: The rational roots theorem applies as easily to a quartic as to a quadratic.

Comment: The quartic in x is super messy, though. I don't know the rational root theorem; can somebody please explain it to me and apply it to this problem? Thanks :)

Comment: @Fleccerd For a monic polynomial with integer coefficients, the only possible rational roots are integers that divide the constant term. That's the most commonly used form of the rational root theorem. As an example, $x^4+3x^2-4x-1$ can't have rational  roots, as $\pm 1$ are the only allowed rational roots according to the rational root theorem (because the constant term is $1$), and those don't work.

Comment: Once you have $-x^2+ a- \sqrt{x+ a}= 0$ I would think that writing it as $-x^2+ a= \sqrt{x+ a}$ and  **then** squaring both sides would be obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Since the quartic equation is monic, i.e. it has the form
$$x^4+ \dots =0$$
by the rational root theorem, $x$ must be an integer. Moreoever
$$x=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a+x}}>0$$
so that $x$ must be a positive integer.
Now, consider the equation
$$\sqrt{a+x}=a-x^2$$
and call $$y=\sqrt{a+x}=a-x^2$$
Note that $y=\sqrt{a+x}>0$ is a positive integer. Then you have the two equations
$$y^2=a+x$$
$$y=a-x^2$$
Subtracting the two equations side by side you get
$$y^2-y=x+x^2$$
which can be written as
$$y(y-1)=(x+1)x$$
which has a unique positive solution: $y=x+1$.
Thus
$$a=x^2+y=x^2+x+1$$
So you have to find the smallest number $a$ which can be represented as $a=x^2+x+1$ where $x$ is a positive integer, and $x^2+x+1>1000$.
Now, $x=32$ is the smallest integer solution, and $$a=32^2+32+1=1057$$ is the number you were looking for.

Comment: I'd write $y^2−y=x^2+x$ as $y^2−y+\frac14=x^2+x+\frac14$ $\Rightarrow$ $y-\frac12=x+\frac12$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $y=x+1$.

Comment: The above idea is very good. I want to show that, in this case, the fourth degree equation from the beginning can be easily solved as follows. The equation $x^4 - 2ax^2 - x + a^2 - a = 0 $ is written as a quadratic equation in $a$ : $a^2 - (2x^2 + 1)a + x^4 - x = 0. $ It has the solutions: $a_1 = x^2 + x + 1$  and $a_2 = x^2 - x$.

Comment: @medicu: This approach is valuable in giving us a grip on the possible "artifact" solutions that might arise from squaring both sides of the equation.  Here the smallest $a_2 \gt 1000$ is $1056$ (rather than $1057$).  However this would only be a solution if the term $\sqrt{a_2 + x}$ were assigned to be the negative square root $-x$ of $x^2$, while the outer square root is taken to be $x$.